# Have to click twice for jquery to function correctly using show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor, onclick, show-hide

I am trying to show/hide elements using a specific url that pertains to each element(just by having an href, so that each element has a unique url to it). The code I have written out only works when each "a" tag is clicked on twice, otherwise it either displays unrelated content, or hides it altogether. I have explicitly stated them to be display:block in the css file that I have, so I know that isn't the issue, (unless somehow I did this part wrong).

Here is the html I am using:

```
  <div class="faq-intro">
    <div class="faq-list">
      <ul id="main-nav">
        <li class="nav active"><a href="#shipping">Shipping</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#returns">returns</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#custom">Custom Orders</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#replacements">Replacements/ Warranty</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#mostFAQs">Most Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#RAD">RAD Principles</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#environmental">Environmental Stewardship</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#USA">MADE in the USA</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-faq-container">
    <div class="faq-container">
      -content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="faq-container">
      -content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="faq-container">
      -content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="faq-container">
      -content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="faq-container">
      -content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="faq-container">
      -content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="faq-container">
      -content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="faq-container">
      -content goes here
    </div>
  </div>
```

javascript (the constructor takes its arguments from the "new Faq", which is found in another file):

```
new Faq($("#main-nav"), $("div.faq-container"));

export default class Faq {

constructor($navigation, $content) {
  this.$navigation = $navigation;
  this.$content = $content;

  this._bindEvents();
}

_bindEvents() {
  this.$navigation.on("click", ".nav", (event) => {
    this._toggleContent();
  });
}

  _toggleContent() {
    this.$content.hide();
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("shipping") > -1) {
    this.$content.eq( "0" ).show();
  }
  else if (window.location.href.indexOf("returns") > -1) {
    this.$content.eq( "1" ).show();
  }
  else if (window.location.href.indexOf("custom") > -1) {
    this.$content.eq( "2" ).show();
  }
  else if (window.location.href.indexOf("replacements") > -1) {
    this.$content.eq( "3" ).show();
  }
  else if (window.location.href.indexOf("mostFAQs") > -1) {
    this.$content.eq( "4" ).show();
  }
  else if (window.location.href.indexOf("RAD") > -1) {
    this.$content.eq( "5" ).show();
  }
  else if (window.location.href.indexOf("environmental") > -1) {
    this.$content.eq( "6" ).show();
  }
  else {
    this.$content.eq( "7" ).show();
  }
}
}
```

relevant SCSS:

```
    .faq-container {
      display: block;
      &:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
      }
    }
```

any suggestions?

Comment: @WaisKamal what do you mean? this is the first time that I ask this. The other similar questions I had found on SO provided the solution of display: block, which is not working in this situation.

Comment: Unrelated, but FYI, if you put the potential `window.location.href` strings in an array (in the same order than you check them with your `if` statements currently), you can then get rid of all the `if` statements and replace them with just `this.$content.eq( YourArrayName.indexOf(window.location.href)).show();`

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you. I will implement this.

Comment: Sorry @user14450186 I meant to comment on another question :(

Comment: @WaisKamal its totally fine!